# Hide tags in Gitkraken

Tags: gitkraken

In a repo that I'm working on, new tags are created at every merge. So there are tags on all the commits, which creates a problem in finding branch names in the list, I want to hide all the tags at once as there are too many (1k+) to remove one by one.

Comment: have you already tried to right click your branch and choose 'solo'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [version 3.6.0](https://support.gitkraken.com/release-notes/3x/#version-360), the following feature was added:

- Reduce the drag on your graph by using the new context menu option to Hide all tags

Right clicking any single tag will provide the options to Hide/Show all tags along with hiding and soloing the individual tag.

[image]